# Can JavaScript pull loaded webpage source as text?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm fairly new to web and javascript stuff so I'm not sure if you can do this.  Is there a way for something like ajax to get the loaded source of a URL you provide it as text for string parsing?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Longer answer: Yes, with restrictions. I suggest you read more about AJAX first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

An example of how to do it:

```
<body>


 <div id="siteloader"></div>​
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://tired.com/">');
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Always amazed by the gratuitous use of libraries. Why not `document.getElementById('siteloader').innerHTML = '<object data="http://tired.com/">';` and ditch the overhead?